# Custom inspector doesn't save properites in scriptable object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a custom inspector for a scriptable object, but when i reopen my project all the values are reset. Also tried EditorUtility.SetDirty(data); and EditorUtility.SetDirty(this); and neither of them helped.

```
#region Editor
#if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomEditor(typeof(ItemData))]
public class ItemDataEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        ItemData data = (ItemData)target;

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Name", GUILayout.MaxWidth(80));
        data._name = EditorGUILayout.TextField(data._name, GUILayout.MaxWidth(120));
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        if (data._isEatable)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Calories", GUILayout.MaxWidth(80));
            data._calories = EditorGUILayout.IntField(data._calories, GUILayout.MaxWidth(40));

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Water", GUILayout.MaxWidth(80));
            data._water = EditorGUILayout.IntField(data._water, GUILayout.MaxWidth(40));
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
    }
    #endif
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case very often

=> Do **not** directly access and edit the `target`!

Otherwise you would need to manually set according object as *dirty* so that the serializer notes that there are changes to store.

Rather go through `SerializedProperty`!

Somewhat like e.g.

```
#region Editor
#if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomEditor(typeof(ItemData))]
public class ItemDataEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty name;
    private SerializedProperty eatable;
    private SerializedProperty calories;
    private SerializedProperty water;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // enough to link these ONCE to save some performance
        // BTW: There isn't really the need for a `name` in ScriptableObject / MonoBehaviour
        // They already have a name anyway ...
        name = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ItemData._name));
        eatable = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ItemData._isEatable));
        calories = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(data._calories));
        water = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(data._water));
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // base.OnInspectorGUI();

        // Updates the serializedObject (and SerializedProperties) with the current values
        serializedObject.Update();

        // EditorGUILayout.Space();

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(name);
        EditorGUILayout.Propertyfield(eatable);

        // EditorGUILayout.Space();

        if (eatable.boolValue)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.Space();

            using(new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope())
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(calories);
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(water);

                // Or you can still do the manual layouting you had 
                //EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Calories", GUILayout.MaxWidth(80));
                //EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(calories, GUIContent.none, GUILayout.MaxWidth(40));

                //EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Water", GUILayout.MaxWidth(80));
                //EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(water, GUIContent.none, GUILayout.MaxWidth(40));
            }
        }

        // serializes (applies) back any changed SerializedProperties 
        // + handles Undo/Redo and dirty marking => saving
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
#endif
#endregion
```